# Undefined method calling Google Drive Client

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-client

Based on the example provided in [Google's page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples), I installed Google Client SDK via Composer. And trying to use the following codes to upload a file to Google Drive:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

/**
 * Insert new file.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
 * @param string $description Description of the file to insert.
 * @param string $parentId Parent folder's ID.
 * @param string $mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
 * @param string $filename Filename of the file to insert.
 * @return Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile The file that was inserted. NULL is
 *     returned if an API error occurred.
 */
function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($title);
  $file->setDescription($description);
  $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

  // Set the parent folder.
  if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
  }

  try {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();

    return $createdFile;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

$client_email = 'drive-ocr-service@angelic-tracer-123606.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('key.p12');
$scopes = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    //'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
    //'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly'
);
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
// https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples
$response = insertFile($service, 'Test Image for OCR', 'Image for OCR', null, 'image/jpeg', 'test1.jpg');
if($response === NULL) {
    echo 'Upload failed' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    var_dump($response);
}
?>
```

The `insertFile()` function is copied from the example page, but when I run the script, it shows:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile::setTitle()

Is there anything I missed during setup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `$file->setTitle($title);`
use `$file->setName($filename);`

**Edit 2**

`Insert()` method is being replaced by `create()`,

[Use create() instead of insert()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create#auth)

So basically the new code will be(not tested) ,

```
 $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));
```

Comment: Are you saying that the example is not updated / the library is updated ? Where can I find the updated example ? It works, but next error appears: `
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource::insert()` in line `$createdFile = $service->files->insert()`

Comment: Insert()  mehod is being replaced by create(), you can find it here https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create#request